# Fgets from the file until end of line

Tags: c, fgets

I tried using mygets function so that the fgets will only read one line:

```
void * mygets(char *name, int len, FILE * stream)
{
    fgets(name,len,stream);

    if (name[strlen(name) - 1] == 10)
    {
        name[strlen(name) - 1] = 0;
    }
}
```

And the file content is:

```
John Smith //Name

19 // Age

175.62 // Height

87  // Weight
```

Using single linked-list, I just wanted the `*mygets` to read only until `John Smith` then store it to a typedef struct named `client` by:

```
typedef struct nodebase{
    char name[40]; //Just in case, the client's name can be long
    int age;
    double height;
    int weight;
    struct nodebase *next;
    }listnode;

int main()
{
listnode *head;
listnode *tail;
listnode *client;
FILE *f;

f=fopen("filename.txt","r");

while(!feof(filename))
{
    client = malloc(sizeof(listnode));
    mygets(client->name,40,filename);

    if (head == NULL)
    {
        head = client;
    }
    else 
    {
        tail->next=client;
    }
    tail = client;
    client =head;
}

while(client!=NULL)
{
    printf("\n%s\n",&client->name);
    client = client->next;
}

}
```

But the problem is, the program prints the entire file (including the age, height, and weight).

I cannot find anything wrong with my `*mygets`.

***I am using Tiny C on Windows

Answer (score 1):

You have lots of typos and mistakes in the code you have posted in your question.

1. `FILE *f` declaration doesn't end with semicolon;
2. Condition in `while(client!NULL)` is not valid C condition, it should be `!=` there;
3. `head` and `tail` did not declared.

I hope that by the way you have working version of this code.

What is about your question, the code just works as it is written - your `mygets` function reads a line from the file, so in your `while(!feof(filename))` loop you read file contents line by line (name, age, height, weight) and put entries into the linked-list. Then you just print them by traversing linked list from beginning to the end.

Comment: What I wanted the code to do is to assign each individual lines into the variables in the Typedef struct.

Comment: But you read only name in your `mygets(client->name,40,filename);`. You should read also age, height, weight from file and fill appropriate fields of your structure.

Comment: Let me rephrase my question, the code is supposed to ONLY read the name in my `mygets(client->name,40,filename);` but it reads the ENTIRE content of the file...